# howto enable jre8 for a specific project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a lot of projects in my eclipse running with JRE7 as standard.
I like to run one specific java project with JRE8. Howto configure this ?

My settings so far. I have JRE7 and JRE8 installed and JRE7 set as default:

[image]

I have my project settings where I try to assign the project to a JRE8.

[image]

Howto do ?

Comment: What version of eclipse are you running?

Comment: Install a version of eclipse that supports Java 8. Luna has built in support, and I believe there is an update for Kepler. Any earlier version(s) don't support Java 8 compliance level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For java8 support go to eclipse marketplace and search and install

`Java™ 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2`

[image]

For additional features install:

- Java 8 Facet for Web Tools for Eclipse Kepler SR2 for Java EE
  developers
- Java 8 support for m2e for Eclipse Kepler SR2 for Maven integration in Eclipse

Or you can install Eclipse Luna which has built in java 8 support.

You can download Luna from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).